# local tag name from xml.etree.ElementTree in python?

Tags: python, xml

Why is there no method in the ElementTree API for the local element tag name?
I get the fully-qualified name from element.tag, as .e.g.

```
{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1}dependentAssembly
```

The helper class `QName` doesn't have such a method.

I end up with code like

```
fulltag.split('}')[-1]
```

and feel strongly I've missed something?

Searching for solutions, I invariably end up with the 'cousin' project
lxml.etree, which DOES include `.localname`.

Comment: have you tried text method? e.g. for child in root: print child.text

Comment: no, child.text would be the element text-node contents, not the local element tag name.

Comment: I 'solved' this, by abandoning ElementTree, after seeing that would also 'scramble' the namespaces when persisting the updated file.
 The output was legal, but broke the brittle tools (AKA 'visual studio') the xml was intended for.